# With Python win32com how to get a reference to a chart data table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, powerpoint-2013

With Python win32com how to get a reference to a chart data table?

I can create a chart with a data table (PowerPoint pops it up in a separate window)
like:

```
    import win32com
    from MSO import constants as msoconst

    Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    Application.Visible = True
    Presentation = Application.Presentations.Add()

    FirstSlide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)

... no problem adding slides, shapes and text and setting font size and color ....

    InventoryChart = FirstSlide.Shapes.AddChart2(201,msoconst.xlColumnClustered ,10,80,470,220,False) # 0 = Clustered Column, 1 = Combo Area, 2 = Clustered Column
    InventoryChartData = InventoryChart.ChartData
```

ChartData doesn't work: AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'ChartData'

So, how do you get a reference to the table that PowerPoint creates? Or how do I define the table to be used for my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question a while back and spent a lot of time trying to find an answer.

ChartData is a property of the [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/chart-object-powerpoint) object. So to access the ChartData object, you need to tell PowerPoint that the shape you just added is a Chart.

Here are two ways to do do that.

```
# Option 1 - Add .Chart to end of AddChart2 method
InventoryChart = FirstSlide.Shapes.AddChart2(201,msoconst.xlColumnClustered,10,80,470,220,False).Chart

# Option 2 - Define Chart object separate from AddChart2
InventoryChart = FirstSlide.Shapes(1).Chart

# You can now access the chart's data worksheet
InventoryChartData = InventoryChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

# Write a value to worksheet
InventoryChartData.Range('F1').Value = 150

# Apply numeric formatting to Series 1 values
InventoryChartData.Range('B2:B5').NumberFormat = '0.00'
```